# link_to helper doesn't work for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the controller file drummer.rb

and I use both old controller/action way and new resource way, either work
the view file index.html.erb:

```
<ul>
<% @drummer_list.each do |d| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to :controller => 'drummers',:action => 'show', :id => '@drummer'  do %>
      <%=  d.first_name + ' ' + d.last_name %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

the resource way:

```
<ul>
<% @drummer_list.each do |d| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to drummers_path(@drummer)  do %>
      <%=  d.first_name + ' ' + d.last_name %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

when I click each link, in the browser url bar give me this

```
http://localhost:3000/drummers/@drummer
```

it should give me

```
http://localhost:3000/drummers/1
```

I think the problem is about the @drummer, I'm not sure about the it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :)

```
<ul>
<% @drummer_list.each do |d| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "#{d.first_name} #{d.last_name}", drummers_path(d) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you wanted to use "d" instead of "@drummer" as that's your loop variable of the drummer instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<% @drummer_list.each do |d| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "#{d.first_name} #{d.last_name}", d %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I would move this into a collection partial if it gets more complicated.